# Transparent textures in Android OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparency, textures

I'm trying to make an app in Android in which you can put different tipes of clothes on different characters.To do this i have made a square on which i put a texture (the character) with transparency (so you ca see the background, arround him) and then i added another square where the texture is the piece of clothing.The problem is that both squares with their specific textures show the backgroud, but the second square does not show the square behind him.

I guess my question is how can i make the second square show the first square and the background on the transparent parts?

Comment: Are you rendering the transparent square *after* the solid square, or the other way around? When using transparency order matters.

Comment: Hmm i think i understand what you mean.I've read before about order.I'll look into it, i'm still new at this.Thanks!

Comment: And of course, make sure that blending is enabled and that the correct blend function is set ;)

Answer (score 0):

make use of the Alpha component. which adds transparency to the pixel.
Look at this [link](http://graphics.wikia.com/wiki/Alpha_blending)vwhich help you better

Comment: Thanks for the reply!I've tried with the Alpha component.
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); But unfortunately it only works partially.I get the effect i want but, the second square with the texture has a transparency effect on it, and you can see the backgroun through it.Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dorin Can you post the code which has the problem. i assume you can control the transparency on each texture.